# variable inside another variable

Tags: javascript, regex

hi there
i wanted to put this:

```
document.write("y = " + i);
```

inside another variable, like this:

```
s=s+"\"y = \" \+ i";
```

but now, i variable is not variable, just a plain text.

how can i fix this?
output would be

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=s;
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass to `s` string a variable - just text `i`. Try with:

```
s=s+"y = " + i;
```

You can also convert it to:

```
s += "y = " + i;
```

Comment: omg, i can't believe it. I am stuck with this for more than hour and i would never try this one. thanks